# Emacs: evaluating (buffer-file-name) vs. reading variable buffer-file-name?

Tags: emacs, elisp

To get the file name of the current buffer, are the following equivalent?

(1) `(buffer-file-name)` and

(2) `buffer-file-name`.

Are there reasons to prefer one over the other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, when there is a function and a variable with the same name, use the function, not the variable, if you want to be sure to get the most up-to-date value.  In some cases, the variable value is a cache of the computed value, so which you want can depend on how much time you want to spend vs how badly you need the latest value.

But anyway, this is just a *fall-back* guideline.  ***Always consult the doc*** of each, including in the Elisp manual.  And if you have access to the source code, consult that as well.  In this case, the doc makes no case for one or the other, and the source code is C (I don't have it).

In this case, the doc does not indicate any reason to use one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

They should be the same, according to my understanding of the source:

Here's the variable:

```
DEFVAR_PER_BUFFER ("buffer-file-name", &BVAR (current_buffer, filename)
```

And here's the relevant part of the function:

```
return BVAR (current_buffer, filename);
```

They both return the exact same location, only the variable does so by
dereferencing a pointer and the function additionally works for
buffers other than a current buffer. I'm guessing that the function
has a small overhead compared to the variable, although I'm not sure
since I haven't seen the code of dereferencing a buffer-local
variable.